# How to save the Picture content to Neo4J Database? About Java IO

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, neo4j

I am a freshman in Neo4J. I think I am also a freshman in Java though I have learn it for neary 2 years.

I want to save and read a picture in neo4j database, I have a InputStream instance, Its cotent is a picture data. I have a Resoucre Object. it has a byte[] property used to save the picture data. so I do that

```
public static Resource getResourceInstance(InputStream in, String title) throws IOException{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedInputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(in);
    int b;
    while((b = input.read()) != -1){
        sb.append(b);
    }
    input.close();
    in.close();
    return new Resource(sb.toString().getBytes(), title, 0, 0);
}
```

then I use a transaction to save it to neo4j. and I check it by neo4j-server. in database, the byte array is number like 51,52,45 and so on

the second step I want to read the byte array from database.

I put it in Resource Object. and use FileOutputStream read it the code like this

```
        images = resource.getImage();
        String titleString = resource.getTitle();
        String path = "images" + File.separator + titleString + ".jpg";
        System.out.println(Paths.get(path).toRealPath());
        BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(path)));
        out.write(images);
        out.close();
```

this is a Java web project.

**I don't know why I have to create a file in path(String path = "images" + File.separator + titleString + ".jpg";) at first.**

**though I do so, I can't open the file like a picture.**

I am very dispirited now. and I don't konw how to do. can you help me?
thank you very much.

PS:
my english is poor,bet your tolerating.

Answer (score 2):

don't do this in the first place.

store the picture on a filesystem or a public storage like s3, dropbox etc. and save the url or filename in the neo4j property.

If you want to read a file into a byte[] create an array of the file.length() size and read into that array using the right offset until is. read() returns -1

Comment: Thank you very much. I had soved it like you said. It is the only way I can use.